# Question about Notation for Quotient Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Studying intro topology, and I'm told to let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and to let $A\subset X$ be a nonempty closed subset. Then, I'm told to consider the Quotient Space $X/A$.

I don't understand what this means. I thought a quotient space had to be under some equivalence relation ~, and then $X/$~ is a Quotient space. But, $A$ is just a subset??

Can someone explain what exactly this notation means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implied equivalence relation here is that all elements in $A$ are equivalent to each other, while all other points are only equivalent to themselves.

Essentially, you are collapsing $A$ to a single point.

Explicitly, $X/A = X/\sim$, where $\sim$ is defined as $x \sim y$ if and only if $x, y \in A$ or $x = y$.